# How to poll mouse and keyboard when playing a DirectX game

Tags: python, directx, pyautogui, hotkeys, pynput

I have written this code to spam `[` when Capslock and Left Mouse are being clicked. This works completely fine when using it but as soon as im ingame this stops working as directx seems to interfere.

I've already tested https://github.com/learncodebygaming/pydirectinput and this works for sending keystrokes to the game but how can i create hotkeys/poll my keys when ingame so i can handle them?

This is the code:

```py
import customtkinter
from pynput import keyboard, mouse


class Root(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # set up
        self.title("Hotkey handler")
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        self.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.8)
        self.geometry('125x20+470+0')
        self.attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.overrideredirect(1)

        # Create a transparent window
        # self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'gray14')

        self.label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            self, text="Hotkey status: ", fg_color="gray14")
        self.label1.pack(side=customtkinter.LEFT)

        self.label2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            self, text="Ready", fg_color="gray14")
        self.label2.pack(side=customtkinter.RIGHT)

        self.hotkey_status = False
        self.click_status = False

        # The key combination to check
        self.COMBINATIONS = [{keyboard.Key.caps_lock}]

        # The currently active modifiers
        self.current = set()
        self.keyboard = keyboard.Controller()

        self.keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_press_release)
        self.keyboard_listener.start()

        self.mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(
            on_click=self.on_click)
        self.mouse_listener.start()

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed:
            self.click_status = True
        else:
            self.click_status = False

    def on_press(self, key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS]):
            self.current.add(key)
            self.hotkey_status = True
            self.label2.configure(text_color="green")
            if any(all(k in self.current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS):
                self.execute()

    def on_press_release(self, key):
        self.hotkey_status = False
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS]):
            self.current.remove(key)
            self.label2.configure(text_color="#DCE4EE")

    def execute(self):
        if self.hotkey_status and self.click_status:
            self.label2.configure(text_color="red")
            self.keyboard.type("[")


root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the relation with directX here?

Comment: @SimonMourier Games that use DirectX use DirectInput to process data from input devices (keyboard, mouse, controller...) don't recognize the keystrokes sent by the keyboard, pynput or pyautogui module as they seem to use another api than the one used by DirectX

Comment: Games using DirectX do what they want for input. To simulate input on Windows use SendInput API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: @SimonMourier the problem isn't sending input, that works when using pydirectinput but my issue is that im using pynput's keyboard listener to activate my hotkey and that does not work when im ingame